Design of experiment: non-constant factor
I want to set up a design of experiments (to study the growth rate of my cells) with 3 factors (3 levels), however one of my factors is hard to control, I can't keep it constant during the treatment/experimental run. I am not entirely sure how I can keep this factor as it is or could I just define this factor as 'the condition at the start'?
The factors are: light intensity (I can control this); temperature (controlled) and nutrients (I can't control this as the nutrients will be used during the treatment).
So could I simply define this as 'nutrients at the start' and leave it as such?
The output (Y) would be the growth of my cells. I am interested in knowing the influence of the light, temperature and concentration of nutrients.
As far as I understand it you should be able to control your factors during your treatment if you can't , you shouldn't be doing a DOE set up.
I am not sure whether I can still run it as such or I should opt for another approach. In theory one could take samples each day and add extra nutrients to stay at the start level (to keep the nutrients constant throughout the growth) but this is practically difficult to do.
Any advise?

It would be OK to use the nutrient content at the beginning of the experiment as a factor, but it is technically possible to hold the nutrients constant by growing the cells within a flow chamber.

I see no fundamental issue with the factor being "nutrients at the start". One could imagine that more nutrients at the start (to a point) would lead to faster initial growth, but of course this would lead to faster consumption of said nutrients, which may lead to some equilibrium after some time. Now, this is not the same condition as maintaining a constant amount of nutrients throughout the entire experiment, but it is a perfectly valid condition.
